# Documentation about kendo-angular-resize-sensor

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

We have many cases where we have to change kendo grid height when our container is resized.
I have seen on npm package: @progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor
but i really don't see any documentation published.

Will be available in future?
if yes when?

So thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top priority is to get the Grid to be responsive "by default". This includes automatic resizing and min-width settings for the columns.

For the moment you can use the [following snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/UYxZhtEq7dnYjerEWTGe?p=preview) as a manual alternative to these features.

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <kendo-grid
        [height]="gridHeight">
        ...
    </kendo-grid>
    <!-- An internal component that will soon go public -->
    <kendo-resize-sensor (resize)="resize()"></kendo-resize-sensor>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public gridHeight: number = 300;

    public resize(): void {
      // The Grid height is actually applied to the content area, not as total
      // This is **a bug** that will be fixed soon.
      this.gridHeight = this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight - 100;
    }

    ...
}
```

We were hoping to keep the resize sensor as an implementation detail. Still, it might find use in client applications. We'll add documentation for it in the coming weeks.

Comment: I am still getting following error:
ng:///ChartModule/ChartComponent.ngfactory.js:50 ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at computedProp (vendor.bundle.js:110777)
    at ResizeSensorComponent.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor/dist/es/resize-sensor.component.js.ResizeSensorComponent.ngAfterViewChecked